# Change color for a label which does not have 'Id'

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change text color for a label element which does not have 'ID'. I cannot edit the HTML but I can provide JQuery or can update the CSS class. I am doing this on a portal whose instance I'm customizing as per our look and feel needs, and it does not offer a way to edit HTML, but let the user update jquery and CSS.

Check box and label for checkbox are placed in a div, as follows. I tried adding "color: white" in 'loginbx' class but it didn't work. Could you please suggest how could this be done using jquery?

```html
<div class="loginbx">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showPwd">
    <label for="showPwd">
        Show Password
    </label>
</div>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your css selector would be: `.loginbx > label` or just `.loginbx label { color: white; }` incase your real code is slightly more complicated.

Comment: @freedomn-m *where did you get white [...] from?* -- I read the `white` between the lines, I saw the label *Show Password* for the checkbox and so I really expected this choice of color ... and obviously stopped reading then ;-)

Comment: @Wolf interesting, I saw "change colour" / "color:white" and I assumed the background was non-white (eg dark blue) and OP was trying to make it *more* legible (eg currently light-blue on dark-blue which some bad designers seem to like).  I guess it could be that it's to be white-on-white, but then why not just ask for it to be removed/hidden? (but then people do ask XY Problems frequently, so could be that).

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the reply. Honestly. I must admit that I've been pretty negative lately, your hint made it even clearer to me.

Comment: @Jaqen H'ghar `color: white` -- This and not adding that the background is dark - looks more like fraudulent intent to me than look-and-feel optimization. A screenshot of your starting point might have been more helpful (and less misleading) than the code snippet.

Comment: I agree to that @Wolf

Comment: thank you @freedomn-m and Wolf for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```css
#showPwd + label {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbx">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showPwd">
    <label for="showPwd">
        Show Password
    </label>
</div>
```

OR jQuery:

```js
$( "#showPwd" ).next().css( "color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loginbx">
    <input type="checkbox" id="showPwd">
    <label for="showPwd">
        Show Password
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It may not have an ID but it does have a singular *attribute* - `for` which you target.

```css
label[for="showPwd"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbx">
  <input type="checkbox" id="showPwd">
  <label for="showPwd">
        Show Password
    </label>
</div>
```